# Firebase Index with Key as Parent

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm getting an error from Firebase:

> Error: No index defined for read. FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding ".indexOn": "read" at /checkins to your security rules for better performance.

My data structure is:

```
checkins: {
  -KwlbakCMOcjs1UhlqLv: {
    read: true,
    user: "someuserid"
  },
  -KwlysmdbSCfTI_Nz0Wo: {
    read: false,
    user: "someotherid"
  }
}
```

As you can see, the direct child of `checkins` is a key. Based on the error message, I've tried multiple ways of writing my rules, but the error persists:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    "checkins": {
      "$checkinid": {
        ".indexOn": "read"
      }
    }
  }
}

{
  ..
  "checkins": {
    "$checkinid": {
      ".indexOn": ["read"]
    }
  }
}

{
  ..
  "checkins": {
    ".indexOn": "read"
  }
}

{
  ..
  "checkins": {
    ".indexOn": ["read"]
  }
}
```

Funny thing is: I tried to switch it up to indexOn user, but then I get an error there too (same idea - no index defined). `checkins` is not a child of anything, and there are no other rules but the ones you see for read/write at this point.

If it helps, my query is:

```
db.ref( 'checkins' ).orderByChild('read').equalTo(false).on(...
```

and I tried with `user` as the index on:

```
db.ref( 'checkins' ).orderByChild('user').on(...
```

So am I missing some key thing here? Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Those last two `.indexOn` definitions should work, as long as your data structure is indeed `/checkins`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this:

```
     "$checkinid": {
        ".indexOn": "read"
      }
```

And add this line inside "checkins" node as firebase suggestion, then you'll see the magic:

```
".indexOn": "read"
```

So your rule should become:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    ".indexOn": "read"
  }
}
```